# What mistake am I making trying to calculate the line integral $\oint_C3xy^2dx+8x^3dy$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-function

> Evaluate the line integral
>   $$\oint_C3xy^2dx+8x^3dy$$
>   where $C$ is the boundary of the region between the circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=64$ having positive orientation.

I actually used Green's theorem to find this. I know $r$ ranges from $1$ to $8$ and $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi$.

Okay, so I found $\dfrac{d}{dx}8x^3=24x^2$, and $\dfrac{d}{dy}3xy^2=6xy$.

Now I'm integrating $24x^2-6xy$. I converted it to polar coordinates and took the integral and I got $0$. However this is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To integrate $24x^2\mathrm dx-6xy\mathrm dy$ you that $C$ equals the boundary of the given region. What $C$ are you using?

Comment: C is the boundary of the region between the circles x^2+y^2=1 and x^2+y^2=64. So I converted to polar because I thought it would be easier to integrate

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. Please parametrize $C$.

Comment: do you mean like x=cost and y=sint would be for circle one and for circle two we have x=8cost and y=8sint???

Comment: Your method is fine. Double check your double integral computation, in particular your bounds on $\theta$.

Comment: Well I got the bounds from my textbook because there was a similar problem in the book.

Comment: @Ayoshna Yes, it would be something like that. But then $C$ isn't a [piecewise smooth curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field) and you need that for the integral to make sense. To use Green's Theorem you need to brake up the boundary in two sets which you piecewise smooth-parametrize and go from there. See the section below example 2 [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A direct integration around the two circles involves (by convention) following the larger circle counter-clockwise ("positive" direction) and then the smaller circle clockwise ("negative" direction).  Applying polar coordinates, the integral becomes

$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} \ 3 \ (r \cos \theta) \ (r \sin \theta)^2 \ \ d(r \cos \theta) \ \ + \ \ 8 \ (r \cos \theta)^3 \ \ d(r \sin \theta) $$

with fixed values for $ \ r \ $ .  We would trace the two circles by

$$ 8^4 \ \int_0^{2 \pi} \ -3 \  \sin^3 \theta \ \cos \theta \   +  \ 8 \ \cos^4 \theta \ \ d \theta $$

$$ - \ \ 1^4 \ \int_0^{2 \pi} \ -3 \  \sin^3 \theta \ \cos \theta \   +  \ 8 \ \cos^4 \theta \ \ d \theta $$

$$ = \ \  ( \ 8^4 - 1 \ ) \   \left( \ [ \ 3 \theta \ + \ 2 \ \sin \ 2 \theta \ + \ \frac{1}{4}  \sin \ 4 \theta \ ] \ + \ [ \ \frac{3}{4} \sin^4 \theta \ ] \ \right) \ \vert_0^{2 \pi}   \ \ . $$

Integrating through one full period, all of the terms except the first produce zeroes.  Thus, the value of the integral is

$$ ( \ 8^4 - 1 \ ) \  \cdot \ 3 \cdot \ 2 \pi \ = \ 6 \pi \ ( \ 8^4 - 1 \ ) \ \ \text{or} \ \ 24570 \pi \ \ . $$

This confirms the result found by **Jeb** , applying Green's Theorem over the annulus bounded by the two circles.

Answer (score 0):

Remember greens theorem is:

$\oint_C Ldx+ Mdy  = \int_D ( \partial_x M - \partial_y L ) dx dy $

So in this case we have

$ \oint_C3xy^2dx+8x^3dy = \int _D (24 x^2 -6 xy ) dx dy = \int_1^8 \int_0^{2\pi} r^3( 24  \cos ^2 \theta - 6 \cos \theta \sin \theta ) d\theta dr $

The second term is odd on the interval so it drops, I'll leave you to finish the question. I.e

$  \oint_C3xy^2dx+8x^3dy = 24 \int_1^8 \int_0^{2\pi} r^3  \cos ^2 \theta d \theta dr  = ?
$

hint: use the half angle identity.

Comment: I have solved it and lon capa is still saying it is wrong

Comment: You said you got $0$...the above integral is not zero...

Comment: My new answer, after I took your advice, is 1608.10274

Comment: I didn't get that, you should get $ 3 \pi ( 8^4 -1) $. Check your work!

Comment: That is not right, either

Comment: Try $6 \pi ( 8^4 -1)$, I feel like I interpreted the question wrong from you. If $D$ is the region bounded completely by the 2 circles that you mentioned, then we're missing a factor of 2.

Comment: why am I missing a factor of two? I can't try it I used all my 8 tries

Comment: Because when you rotate around, we need to go from 0 to 360 ( $0$ to $2 \pi$), not from $0$ to $180$ like you stated above ( $ 0$ to $\pi$)

Comment: I agree with your latter answer; I also get that result by direct line integration around the two circles.  (I'll post that presently.)

Comment: But I thought since it was positive orientation I only go from 0 to 180

Comment: Positive orientation in this case means we go from $ 0$ to $360$ degrees (counter clockwise), not from $ 0$ to $-360$ (clockwise). Notice in both cases we rotate the same amount, but we choose ccw to be positive and cw to be negative. The only effective difference is a sign.